# Ace Editor Plugin for MVC Razor syntax

Tags: ace-editor

How i can create a plugin for ACE Editor to support Razor syntax.
Ace Home Page: http://ace.c9.io

Comment: possible duplicate of [Razor syntax highlighting for Ace editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913932/razor-syntax-highlighting-for-ace-editor)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a started implementation of Razor syntax highlighting in ACE. All credits goes to [Andrey Shchekin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39068/andrey-shchekin) a member of Stack Overflow.

[Download his branch of the ACE from GIT](https://github.com/ashmind/ace/tree/razor-wip-shelf). In Node.JS command prompt go to the directory and do the following:

1. `npm install`
2. `node Makefile.dryice.js full`

Then copy the src folder that you want to work with and configure ace like this.

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome_razor"); //Razor CSS
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/razor"); //Razor Syntax!!!
```

A sample of how it looks like

[image]

**Thank you so much to Andrey for starting this off hopefully it will get a boost now more people can tinker with it.**