# Razor syntax highlighting for Ace editor

Tags: razor, codemirror, ace-editor

Razor is a combination of HTML and C#. But neither [ACE](http://ace.c9.io/) or [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) have Razor in their modes scripts.

Does anybody have a Razor mode for either of these or any other editors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Marked as a dupe since you posted the same answer here and there, then deleted the duplicate answer here.

Comment: Yea, I couldnt mark the other answer as dupe because no answer was accepted. So i reveres the logic but you had the power to do it any way. Thanks. Where the link to the Dupe question any way?

Comment: It's at the top of your question here. No worries! Everything's good. Glad you found your answer :) Wanted to be sure to 'splain what I did here.

Comment: Ahh OK. Now that original question is on hold? Will it get deleted? When searching <search engine> that is one of the first links that came up for me.

Comment: It's actually quite possible it will be deleted, yes.

Comment: IS there any way to prevent it or do you think it is too broad? Or can I undelete my answer here now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question: < [How to do embedded highlightings in Ace editor if embedding requires proper brace nesting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674431/how-to-do-embedded-highlightings-in-ace-editor-if-embedding-requires-proper-brac) > have mostly working c# Razor mode for Ace, you can ask its author to make a pr to Ace.

Comment: He was very kind to provide me with a link to his latest code. Thanks